# Webpack not found when app deployed to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack

I'm getting the error `sh: 1: webpack: not found` when the app is deployed to production. I've tried moving all the dependencies related to webpack from the devDependency list to the dependency list in the package.json file to avail. [The Heroku error log can be seen here for greater insight.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F5aO.png) What steps could be taken to solve this issue?

[image: Heroku error log]

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming 'webpack' is installed as a global package in your heroku environment.

Run webpack directly from your node_modules to avoid having to install it globally, like so...

package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --display-error-details",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running npm run build on postinstall? This works for me.

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```